# React router dom white screen after a few navigations

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on a ReactJS project. Here I am facing an issue with `react-router-dom`. After a few navigations, my screen whites out.

Following is my Router.js file:

```js
// Routes.js
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Category from "./Category";
import ProductDetails from "./ProductDetails";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import Login from "./Login";
import Register from "./Register";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
import Cart from "./Cart";
import Confirm from "./Confirm";
import Home from "./Home";
import UserDashboard from './UserDashboard';

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Category} />
      <Route path="/dash" exact component={UserDashboard} />
      <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/product" exact component={ProductDetails} />
      <Route path="/cart" exact component={Cart} />
      <Route path="/checkout" exact component={Checkout}/>
      <Route path="/confirm" exact component={Confirm}/>
      <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
      <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} />
      <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
    </>
  )
}

export default Routes
```

Following is my App.js file:

```js
// App.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import { BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from "./pages/Routes";

const App = () => {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Suspected code of category section:

```js
// Category.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import BannerText from "../components/BannerText";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import Axios from "axios";
import ProductCard from "../components/ProductCard";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Category = () => {
  const [next, setNext] = useState("");
  const [prev, setPrev] = useState("");
  const [pagdata, setPagdata] = useState([]);
  const [purl, setPurl] = useState([]);
  const [xurl, setXurl] = useState("http://192.168.43.34:8000/api/products/");
  const [imgurl, setImgurl] = useState([]);
  const [caturl, setCaturl] = useState(
    "http://192.168.43.34:8000/api/categories/"
  );
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);
  const [catsurl, setCatsurl] = useState([]);

  // Products
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(xurl).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.previous + "from category");
      return [
        setPrev(response.data.previous),
        setNext(response.data.next),
        setPagdata(response.data.results),
        setPurl(response.data.results.url),
      ];
    });
    // Browse Categories List
    Axios.get(caturl).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.results.children);
      return [setCategory(response.data.results), console.log(category)];
    });
    // Sub Categories List
    Axios.get(caturl).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.results);
      return [setCategory(response.data.results), console.log(category)];
    });
  }, [xurl]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <BannerText title="Product List" />

      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-5">
            <div className="sidebar-categories">
              <div className="head">Browse Categories</div>
              <ul className="main-categories">
                {category.map((category) => {
                  return (
                    <Link to={""}>
                      <li className="main-nav-list">
                        <a
                          data-toggle="collapse"
                          href="#fruitsVegetable"
                          aria-expanded="false"
                          aria-controls="fruitsVegetable"
                        >
                          <span className="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span>
                          {category.breadcrumbs}
                          <span className="number">(53)</span>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </Link>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-xl-9 col-lg-8 col-md-7">
            {/* Start Filter Bar */}
            <div className="filter-bar d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center">
              <div className="sorting"></div>
              <div className="sorting mr-auto">
                <div className="head has-text-white">Browse Categories</div>
                {/* <select>
                                            <option value="1">Show 12</option>
                                            <option value="1">Show 12</option>
                                            <option value="1">Show 12</option>
                                        </select> */}
              </div>
              <div className="pagination">
                <a
                  href="#/"
                  className="prev-arrow"
                  onClick={() => setXurl(prev)}
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                {/* <a href="#/" className="prev-arrow" onClick={()=>{onClickLeft();}}><i className="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> */}
                <a href="#/"></a>
                <a href="#/"></a>
                <a href="#/"></a>
                <a href="#/"></a>
                {/* <a href="#/" className="next-arrow" onClick={()=>setXurl(next)}><i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> */}
                <a
                  href="#/"
                  className="next-arrow"
                  onClick={() => setXurl(next)}
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* End Filter Bar */}
            {/* Start Best Seller */}

            {/* End Best Seller */}
            <section className="lattest-product-area pb-40 category-list">
              <div className="row">
                {pagdata.map((pagdata) => {
                  return (
                    <ProductCard
                      title={pagdata.title}
                      realurl={purl}
                      imageurl={pagdata.url}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </section>
            {/* Start Filter Bar */}
            <div className="filter-bar d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center">
              <div className="sorting mr-auto"></div>
              <div className="pagination">
                <a href="#/" className="prev-arrow">
                  <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#/"></a>
                <a href="#/"></a>
                <a href="#/"></a>
                <a href="#/"></a>
                <a href="#/" className="next-arrow">
                  <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

            {/* End Filter Bar */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* <DealOf /> */}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Category;
```

I am only getting a white screen when I try to navigate from '/' to any other route. It has some 'exact' method. Kindly let me know why that exact method is making issues

Comment: This seems to be a state-managing issue in your code. There is probably an error message shown on the console.

Comment: Hi @Stuck, Thanks for your response. Yes you are right and let me give you an update about my code is that everything is working fine but whenever I navigate from Category to any other route it only appears white screen I tried to remove exact from my category link it is breaking my UI header.

Comment: What is the error message? Also show the code of the components that produce the error.

Comment: Just added the code of category section. Which might have issue.

Comment: ....what is the error message?

Comment: The console is clean. No error the screen just goes off white and requires a reload. I think that this is possibly a react-router-dom implementation issue but I am unable to figure out.   1.Go to the category route 2.Go to any other route 3. White screen(requires reload).

Comment: Hi @AmerllicA I am new here so I don't know a lot about it, but thanks for your response.

Comment: @ShrikantJha, Dear friend, when you wanna navigate from `/` to any routes. which of the above elements is clicked by your hand? the `<a>` tag or the `<Link>`?

Comment: <Link to="/">
                          <a href="#/" className="nav-link">
                            Shop Category
                          </a>
                        </Link>

Comment: Dear @ShrikantJha, there is no need to use useless anchors. pay attention to my answer.

Comment: @AmerllicA it's a <Link>   after clicking on category the category page shows up...but then whenever I try to go on any other page there is a white screen. Then I just have to maually reload to see that page.

Comment: Okay, let me try. @AmerllicA

Comment: @ShrikantJha, your app should work without any reload by your hand or itself. it is a SPA application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For routing on a ReactJS SPA (Single Page Application) you should use the `Link` component of `react-router-dom` but in your code I just see you use anchor `<a>` tags. there is an only `<Link>` tag that its `to` prop is an empty string! pay attention to this part of your code:

```js
  {category.map((category) => {
    return (
      <Link to={""}> // <== here!!!
```

Actually, you should pass one of the route names here like below code:

```js
  {category.map((category) => {
    return (
      <Link to="/dash"> // <== here!!!
```

Furthermore, be cute on ReactJs, there is no need to return on JSX, write the above code like it:

```js
  {category.map((category) => ( // <== return JSX like it
    <Link to="/dash">
```

Other the `<a href="#/"` tags just caused a refresh on your app, hence your app with internal routing with anchor tag is not still a SPA. use `Link` of `react-router-dom`.

Also, the `Link` component in your application is under a `map` function. so your `category` maybe have related route name in it. additionally, I suggest you do not use same name for `array.map` and its items inside the `map` function, write like below:

```js
category.map( item =>
```

I hope these suggestions help you.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the help you provided to me along with really good and professional advices on my code. I have fixed my issue. The issue was in the <ProductCard /> component with useEffect() function. I working on it's improvement.